# PDOStatement: Field 'limitacc' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064, webmin

PDOStatement: Field 'limitacc' doesn't have a default value
[image]

Help Me Please

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory but without seeing any code there is no way anyone can help you debug the problem.

Comment: You've tagged this with 'phpmyadmin' but this error message doesn't seem to be related to the phpMyAdmin program. How have you installed phpMyAdmin and which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Give that field a default value, details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp):

```
ALTER TABLE tblname
ALTER clmname SET DEFAULT ' ';
```